# Desktop Application C# Global variable

Tags: c#, compact-framework, web-config, global-variables

Desktop app

C#

Compact Framework

2 projects in one solution

Main project uses DataAccess project (reference), because everything related to Database is in DataAcess project
I am actually connecting to 2 different databases.

How can I make a "global" variable that would be available from both projects? (without needing to add reference - which, I cannot do, because it would be circular ref)

In web I had (dataaccess part):

```
 string strConnRSS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something1"];
 string strConnRSS = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["something2"];
```

getting data  from the web.config (this was in the web prj):

```
 <appSettings>
 <add key="something1" value="server=...;database=...;uid=...;password=...;" />
 <add key="something2" value="server=...;database=...;uid=...;password=...;" />
 </appSettings>
```

is there something similar in a desktop app?

thanks

Update:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/dotnetcompactframework_app_config.asp
this looks helpful, but we have a settings page, where you can change the actual connection string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a 3rd library, with common code for both your projects like this and add references to it.

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
    public static string SomeCommonVar { get { // read this lib app.config } }
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I meant with having another approach in my previous answer. Better not to have things in the application settings if not needed. Of course, if it is a reference to a database and it is read from some settings file or something I would not object to an AppSetting, but for sharing data this approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I would like to use this approach. I would always think long and hard before I decide to have a global variable like this, perhaps there is some better design/architecture which would allow you to work around this? 
Anyway, you did not state which .Net version you are targeting but here is a code sample for 3.5.

In my exe:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set("TestData", "TestValue");

    string testData = ClassLibrary1.Class1.GetTestData();
    if (testData != null )
        MessageBox.Show(testData);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Not found");
}
```

In my class library:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string GetTestData()
    {
        return ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TestData"];
    }
}
```

The exe obviously have a reference to the class library.

Comment: i did state the version. it's CF (added tags also)

Comment: Did not try this on CF. Different platforms support different versions. You need to look up which version is supported on your platform.

Comment: Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Good that you are optimizing my code abatishchev! =) Sometimes my examples are quick rather than good when it comes to performance..